# Return corresponding value in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
     price     sales
0  9611.89  0.013477
1  9611.88  0.032521
2  9611.87  0.047571
3  9611.86  0.107571
4  9611.81  0.257285

for i in df['price']:
    if i < 9611.87:
        print(i)
        break
```

The above loop returns the correct price. Now, I want it to print the corresponding value of i in the sales column, 0.107571

The below code does not work

```
for (i, ii) in df:
    if i < 9611.87:
        print(ii)
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this without looping.  Pandas indexing is made exactly for this. You can read more about boolean masking (conditional filtering) [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/boolean-indexing-in-pandas/), and other indexing methods [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).

Given the condition of `'price'<9611.87`...

The following will return all columns and the rows of the dataframe with that condition:

```
df[df['price']<9611.87]
```

This will return a series of just the 'sales' column with the rows satisfying that condition:

```
df['sales'][df['price']<9611.87]
```

Lastly, since it looks like you only wanted the first item based on your loop, you can use `.iloc` to get a particular index of the returned series. In this case index 0:

```
df['sales'][df['price']<9611.87].iloc[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to print all the values that are less than 9611.87?
Have you considered filtering, like the following:

```
new_df = df[df['price']<9611.87]
print(new_df)
print(new_df['sales'])
```

Which should give the following output:

```
     price     sales
3  9611.86  0.107571
4  9611.81  0.257285
3    0.107571
4    0.257285
Name: sales, dtype: float64
```